# How to fetch data from protected login portal using php curl

Tags: php, curl, remote-access

So here is the scenario, I am trying to get the content from the user login dashboard which is protected inside the login form. In other words, we need to enter login information before in order to access the source page from where we have to get content.

**login portal URL**: https://xxxxxx.xxx/login

**URL inside the login portal**: https://xxxxxx.xxx/user_profile/dashboard

**Php curl:**

```
<?php

$login_url = ' https://xxxxxx.xxx/login';


//These are the post data username and password
$post_data = 'username=xxxx&password=xxxx';

//Create a curl object
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the useragent
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

//Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );

//This is a POST query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

//Set the post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

//We want the content after the query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//Follow Location redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

/*
Set the cookie storing files
Cookie files are necessary since we are logging and session data needs to be saved
*/

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

//Execute the action to login
$postResult = curl_exec($ch);



$url = "https://xxxxxx.xxx/user_profile/dashboard";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
if(!empty($ch))
{
        $thispage = new DOMDocument;
        Libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $thispage->loadHTML($html);
        Libxml_clear_errors();
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($thispage) ;
        $status = $xpath->evaluate( 'string(//a[contains(text(),"YouTube")])');

        if(strpos($status, "YouTube") !== false) {
        $status = "YouTube";
          echo $status;
        }
        else
        {
           echo 'FALSE'; 
        }

}

else{
echo 'Page not found';
}

?>
```

**inside cookie.txt**
[image: here]

So here I just trying to fetch XPath of the anchor tag (which is inside the login portal) and trying to display its value(Youtube). but unfortunately, the code seems doesn't work. It's return FALSE.

I guess I am missing something important. Kindly any suggestion, code modification & implementation is highly appreciated.

Comment: They might have some protection against [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) (which is exactly what you're trying to do). Impossible for us to know though since we, most likely, haven't built that site.

Comment: No CSRF  protection is there.

Comment: Can you expand on how you concluded that?

Comment: Forget trying to program a curl request. Download postman and try to properly get the curl request parameters from there.

Comment: Because Site is developed by me and Yet i don't implement any CSRF

Comment: For your second request, try to create a new curl handler and configure it with all the needed settings (like using GET, include the cookies etc) and see if that works better.

Comment: okay thanks, will try

Comment: You also have a typo: `$login_url = ' https://xxxxxx.xxx/login'`. There's a space before the URL in the string. That makes it an invalid URL and your request will fail.